# Why is the HEAD commit so named?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm trying to learn Git, and I can't imagine why the `HEAD` pointer would be called that.  If I knew, it would be a lot easier to remember what it means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In computer science in general *head* is the part of a data structure conceptually closest to the observer, such as the first element of a linked list. The opposite is the *tail*, which is the farthest element.

In git `HEAD` is the commit on which you are currently operating, and is obviously the closest commit in the history graph. git is not unique in this naming; [Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.revs.specifiers.html#svn.tour.revs.keywords) and [CVS](http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#update) also used the `HEAD` term for equivalent concepts.